# Pandas remove numeric rows/values from column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How can i remove the rows where a column "Name" contains numeric values.

below is the input df,

```
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14],['00012', 14],['abc123', 14]]
```

Expected result is,

```
    Name    Age
0   tom     10
1   nick    15
2   juli    14
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[~df.Name.str.contains(r'\d')]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df[df.Name.str.isalpha()]
```

**str.isalpha()** checks if all characters in the string are alphabetic, if not return False